# How to remove spaces between text and spinners?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, toolbar

I found an excellent article to add a dropdownlist to the toolbar but the problem is that there are spaces between the text and the spinner. How can I remove the spaces between the text and the spinner?
[link to article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26510930/android-lollipop-add-popup-menu-from-title-in-toolbar/49904731#49904731)

[link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKQA7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go into an article which is your following to achieve. You can see in `onCreateOptionsMenu` they are inflating `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` layout to achieve text and dropdown menu which is the default behavior.

If you want to achieve different behavior as per your requirements then you should create your own spinner layout for that you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52694656/4395804).

Let me know if that can help you. 
Thanks. Happy coding..!

Comment: I hope, you will give upvote as well. 
Thanks for accepting the answer. Happy to help you.